# Set labelsize of tikz/pgfplots-figure to fixed font size independently of scaling factor

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

In my project I have several graphs/figures displaying data. The requirements I got are to use the same font in the text of the main document and in all figures. Therefore, I decided to use pgfplots/tikz for drawing my graphs, but encountered several issues.

One major requirement I got for all documents was to not only use the same font, but also use the same font size for all labels as in the corresponding figure caption, regardless of scaling of the figure. I.e. if I had to shrink a figure by some percent to accommodate text around the figure, the labels of the figure decreased accordingly, which violated that requirement. The solution which was suggested to me was to re-create the document in Word, and add all labels using text boxes, something I'd like to avoid (after having >20 figures in the document).

To demonstrate the problem, I created a small MWE below. It uses three files, `main.tex`, `sub.tex` and `sub2.tex`:
main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.dat}
    x y
    0 0
    1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    4 4
    5 5
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{file2.dat}
    x y
    0 0
    1 1
    2 4
    3 9
    4 16
    5 25
    6 36
    7 49
    8 64
    9 81
    10 100
    11 121
    12 144
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        label style={font=\LARGE\bfseries},
        tick label style={font=\LARGE}  
    },
    y axis/.append style={align=center}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.75\linewidth}
            \includestandalone[width=\linewidth, mode=buildnew,
            ]{sub}\caption{Image I}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.20\linewidth}
            \includestandalone[width=\linewidth, mode=buildnew,
            ]{sub2}\caption{Image II}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

sub.tex:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{file1.dat}{\tablea}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
                \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0, ymax=30,
            xmin=0, xmax=5,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            grid=major,
            legend entries={\(y_1\),\(y_2\),\(y_1+y_2\)},
            legend pos = north west
            ]
            % Select appropriate columns
            \addplot [blue, mark=*] table [x=x,y=y] {\tablea};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

sub2.tex:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}Screenshot_20210208_175745.png
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{file2.dat}{\tablea}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0, ymax=90,
            xmin=0, xmax=10,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            grid=major,
            legend entries={\(y_1\),\(y_2\),\(y_1+y_2\)},
            legend pos = north west
            ]
            % Select appropriate columns
            \addplot [blue, mark=*] table [x=x,y=y] {\tablea};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

I explicitly scaled the figures more than necessary to showcase my issue here. Is there a way to "unscale" the labels and fonts and link their size explicitly to the font size of the figure captions? I'd rather avoid the proposed solution using Word.

Comment: You are including the figures as standalones files, which means that they are treated as images. If you want to respect font size, you should use /input{} instead. This way, every plot is compiled as part of the main document, instead of being treated as separated pictures. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Jes: I can try that, but then I might run into long compilation times (due to a large amount of pictures generated by tikz/pgfplots), which was the reason I split it up in the first place

Comment: You are right. If you are going to re-scale the images, but not change anything else, in these cases I usually create a "clean" PNG file of the plot and then load that on another file and write axis, legends etc on top with tikz/pgfplots. See [this blog](https://latexdraw.com/how-to-annotate-an-image-in-latex/) for an example. It has the advantage of being very fast, but you also need to take care of the png file. But maybe there are other ways, such as saving the images on PDF_TEX, altough I do not like it, as it looks quite ugly when rescaling (text is positioned absolute)

Comment: PS: PDF files generated with standalone should also be valid for this "method"

Comment: If you want to maintain the graphs in separate files, I suggest 1. Use inclugraphics *without* scaling, and 2. change the size of the graph changing `width` and `height`. Otherwise, put the graphs directly in the main file and use `tikzexternalize`